# Prove $x^2 + e^x \ge 1/e$

Tags: inequality, exponential-function

I have a question regarding how to prove $x^2 + e^x \ge 1/e$.
My lecturer told me the proving process can be separated into 3 parts ($x \le -1, x \ge 0$ and $-1 < x < 0$), the first two intervals tell me the equation must $\ge 1$ and thus $> 1/e$. However the problem is how to prove the results come from the interval $(-1, 0)$ are $> 1/e$?
And I have tried to differentiate this equation but $2x + e^x = 0$, seems to make this problem harder:(
Thank u so much:)
Have a beautiful time in 2022~

Comment: $x^{2}+e^{x} \geq e^{x} > \frac  1 e$ if $-1 <x<0$.

Comment: @Kavi that would be a good answer to close the post with if you'd like to add it

Comment: Have a beautiful time in 2022 as well, starting with a decent answer to this question. The derivative approach also works but with a lot more effort : $2x+e^x = 0$ has a unique solution in $(-1,0)$ which is a minima since the second derivative $2+e^x$ is positive here. Then , at the point of minima, we know that $2x=e^x$ so $x^2+e^x = (\frac{e^{x}}{2})^2+e^x$, then you observe that $(\frac{e^{x}}{2})^2+e^x \geq \frac 1e$ for all $x$ by seeing that the LHS is increasing in $x$ and evaluates to $\frac{1+4e}{4e^2}$ at $x=-1$ which is bigger than $\frac 1e$. Works, but lengthy.

Comment: A slight improvement is to use the first-order Taylor polynomial $1+x ≤ e^x$ (check values on either side of 0), where the minimum of $1+x+x^2$ is $3/4 > 1/e$. As $(x^2+e^x)' = 2x + e^x$, the exact minimum requires the Lambert-W function.

Answer (score 5):

$x^{2}+e^{x} \geq 0+e^{x} >e^{-1}$ for $-1 < x<0$ since $e^{x}$ is an increasing function.

Answer (score 0):

Could this perhaps be the first inequality about the exponential function that cannot easily be shown from
$$ \tag{$\star$}e^t\ge t+1\qquad\text{for all }t\in\Bbb R$$
?

Let's see:
$$ \begin{align}x^2+e^x&=\frac{ex^2+e^{x+1}}e\\&\ge \frac{2x^2+e^{x+1}}e&\text{$x^2\ge0$ and $e^1\ge1+1$}\\&\ge \frac{2x^2+x+2}e&e^{x+1}\ge(x+1)+1\\&=\frac{2(x+\frac14)^2+\frac{15}8}{e}\\&\ge \frac{15}{8e}\\&>\frac1e.\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

Consider the function $$f(x)=x^2 + e^x -  \frac 1e$$

$$f'(x)=2x+e^x \qquad \text{and} \qquad f''(x)=1+e^x >0 ~~\forall x$$

The first derivative cancels at
$$2x_*+e^{x_*}=0 \implies x_*=-W\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\implies f(x_*)=W\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) \left(W\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)+2\right)-\frac{1}{e}$$ Since $W\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=-0.351734\sim-\frac 1e$, then $f(x_*)\sim\frac{1}{e^2}-\frac{1}{e}+e^{-1/e} > 0$ and this is the minimum value of the function.